# I need to do multiple updates on my firebase database with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am working on an ionic3 project with firebase and my database is getting messy and needs a lot of updates everywhere. I learnt from an article that I can use firebase cloud functions to do multiple updates on my firebase database. Please, I need a very simplified explanation of firebase function with an example on how to use it on ionic3 or just angular. Where I have most issue is how to view all the cloud functions you created.

Comment: Show some code snippet which you tried, so people can help you.

Comment: to get started with cloud functions check out official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/